# Why does pyautogui's screenshot function sometimes change coordinates for the same position on screen?

Tags: screenshot, pyautogui

Those who have used pyautogui's screenshot function may have experienced the same.

I am building a poker bot, and part of it is taking screenshots of my hand of cards and some other cards that are on screen that is part of an app, however sometimes after I restart my computer (and other times when I don't even restart my computer but stop using my computer for a while), I will need to move the app's screen to capture the same position - why is this?

I have been doing this for a while now and it happens relatively often.

My expectation is for the same pyautogui coordinates on screen to remain constant, irrespective of when I use my computer.
Meaning I expect the same coordinates to point to the same position on screen always - or am I missing something here?